# Error: Could not find or load main class ArrayMain

Tags: java

I made this program on eclipse, i can't seem to get it running. i get `Error: Could not find or load main class ArrayMain`. i thought of changing the file names within the packages to differentiate between the class and main program. i read up on a thread here on stack overflow and found that most people, whom have had this issue say it has to do with the installation of JDK package. anyway i appreciate  any insight.

```java
public class ArrayMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int months;
        months = 12;
        int [] Array  = new int[months];
         months = 12;
        for(int index = 0; index < Array.length; index++)
        {
            Array[index] += 5;
        }

        Arrayp alex = new Arrayp(Array);

        System.out.println("and the highest score is " + alex.gethighest() + "and the lowest score is " + alex.getlowest());
    }


}
```

---

```java
public class Arrayp 
{

    private int [] A;
    public Arrayp(int [] array) 
    {
        A = array;
    }

    public int getlowest()
    {
        int lowest = A[0];
        for(int index = 0; index < A.length; index++)
        {
            if(A[index] < lowest)
                lowest = A[index];

        }
        return lowest;
    }

    public int gethighest()
    {
        int highest = A[0];
        for(int index = 0; index < A.length; index++)
        {
            if(A[index] > highest)
                highest = A[index];

        }
        return highest;
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you show us the packages in which these two source files are?  Also, how are you running your program?

Comment: I removed the [compiler-errors]-tag since the error-message is from trying to run the program. That reminds me: you have compiled your program before trying to run it, haven't you?

Comment: go to projects>clean then try